# Geometric Fibers of the Projection of Parabola to $x$-axis are Two Points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Vakil 9.5 E from FOAG, and is self-study, not a homework problem.

Consider the projection of the parabola $y^2 = x$ to the $x$-axis over $\mathbb Q$, corresponding to the map

$$\mathbb Q[x] \to \mathbb Q[y]$$

given by $x \mapsto y^2$. I wish to show the geometric fibers always are two points unless the fibers are over $0 = [(x)]$.

It seems to me that this boils down to showing that, writing $\mathbb Q[y]$ as $\mathbb Q[x, y]/(x-y^2)$, the spectrum of

$$\mathbb Q[x, y]/(x-y^2) \otimes_{\mathbb Q[x]} \overline{k}$$

is size two for any algebraically closed field $\overline{k}$ containing $\mathbb Q$, but I am not sure how to deal with the presented generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in \overline{k}$ denote the image of $x\in\Bbb Q[x]$ under the map $\Bbb Q[x]\to \overline{k}$ corresponding to the geometric point. Then writing $\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x-y^2)$ as $(\Bbb Q[x])[y]/(x-y^2)$, we see that $$\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x-y^2)\otimes_{\Bbb Q[x]} \overline{k}\cong \overline{k}[y]/(a-y^2).$$

Now, as $a\neq 0$ and $\overline{k}$ is algebraically closed of characteristic not 2, we can write $(a-y^2)=(\sqrt{a}-y)(\sqrt{a}+y)$ with the two ideals on the right distinct and comaximal, and by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we get that $\overline{k}[y]/(a-y^2)\cong \overline{k}\times \overline{k}$, and the spectrum of this ring is two geometric points.

Comment: Of course. It had been so long since I computed the tensor product over k of two non-finitely generated k-algebras that I forgot my basic tensor product properties. Thank you!